# Select specific rows/columns xls file

Tags: python, pandas, xls

I would like to select specific rows and columns in Python. I already use pandas somewhere in my code so I'd prefer a way to do it with this library.

I tried `specific_row = pandas.read_excel('this_file.xls', "Entrees")[3]` and `specific_row = pandas.read_excel('this_file.xls', "Entrees", index_col = 2)[3]` but I can't seem to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "iloc" method and special which rows to select

```
specific_row = pandas.read_excel('this_file.xls', "Entrees").iloc[:3,:] #select 3 rows and every column
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't get why when I enter 7 as index I get the 8th row but I guess there's something special in the 1st one which seems to be index -1.